# Compare two strings in R and see additions, deletions

Tags: r, string

I want to compare two character values in R and see which characters where added and deleted to display it later similar to `git diff --color-words=.` (see screenshot below)

For example:

```
a <- "hello world"
b <- "helo world!"

diff <- FUN(a, b)
```

where `diff` would somehow show that an `l` was dropped and a `!` was added.

The ultimate goal is to construct an html string like this `hel<span class="deleted">l</span>o world<span class="added">!</span>`.

I am aware of `diffobj` but so far I cannot get it to return the character differences, only the differences between elements.

### Output of `git diff --color-words=.`

the output looks like this:
[image: regex output]

Comment: Are trying to use git in R or you just want to use R? Okay with running the command from within R?

Comment: I don't want to run git to get the differene, I just used it as an example to show the expected output. In a way it is replicating what git diff would show.

Comment: so you want the coloring also in R?

Comment: Check these implementations for https://renozao.github.io/pkgmaker/reference/str_diff.html (not as good as you want) or https://github.com/muschellij2/diffr based on Javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Base R has a function [`adist`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/adist.html) that computes the generalized Levenshtein distance. With arguments `count` and `partial` attribute `"trafos"` is set to the sequence of matches, insertions and deletions needed to go from one string to the other. From the documentation, section Value, my emphasis:

> If `counts`  is `TRUE`, the transformation counts are returned as the `"counts"` attribute of this matrix, as a 3-dimensional array with dimensions corresponding to the elements of x, the elements of y, and the type of transformation (insertions, deletions and substitutions), respectively. Additionally, if `partial = FALSE`, **the transformation sequences are returned as the `"trafos"` attribute of the return value, as character strings with elements ‘⁠M⁠’, ‘⁠I⁠’, ‘⁠D⁠’ and ‘⁠S⁠’ indicating a match, insertion, deletion and substitution, respectively**. If `partial = TRUE`, the offsets (positions of the first and last element) of the matched substrings are returned as the "offsets" attribute of the return value (with both offsets -1−1 in case of no match).

```r
a <- "hello world"
b <- "helo world!"
attr(adist(a, b, counts = TRUE), "trafos")
#>      [,1]          
#> [1,] "MMDMMMMMMMMI"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

There is a deletion in the 3rd character and an insertion at the end of string `a`.

Comment: perfect, it even reduces the dependencies!

Comment: One follow up question if you allow me: how can I see what the combined text would be (eg I see that the 12th element is an `I`, now which character is the 12th element?)

Comment: Thank you for this -- it's really helpful. Follow-up question: what do I do if I want to get the row-wise trafos matching string for two string variables?

Comment: @RobertP. What do you mean by row-wise, what is your data structure?

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution using `diffobj::ses_dat()` and splitting the data into its characters before.

```r
get_html_diff <- function(a, b) {
  aa <- strsplit(a, "")[[1]]
  bb <- strsplit(b, "")[[1]]
  s <- diffobj::ses_dat(aa, bb)
  
  m <- cumsum(as.integer(s$op) != c(Inf, s$op[1:(length(s$op) - 1)]))
  
  res <- paste(
    sapply(split(seq_along(s$op), m), function(i) {
      val <- paste(s$val[i], collapse = "")
      if (s$op[i[[1]]] == "Insert")
        val <- paste0("<span class=\"add\">", val, "</span>")
      if (s$op[i[[1]]] == "Delete")
        val <- paste0("<span class=\"del\">", val, "</span>")
      val
    }),
    collapse = "")
  res
}

get_html_diff("hello world", "helo World!")
#> [1] "hel<span class=\"del\">l</span>o <span class=\"del\">w</span><span class=\"add\">W</span>orld<span class=\"add\">!</span>"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

We use `diffobj` to compare configuration files (in more or less production environment), and it works just right.  In your case, wouldn't `diffobj::diffChr` be what you want?

```r
diffobj::diffChr("hello world", "helo world!", color.mode = 'rgb')
```

[image]

Comment: I want to show the colored output only and not the additional characters (@ and > etc) but thank you for giving this example!